# Mapping in Nhibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate 3.3 with vb.net
I am trying to mapping through code but it results in cannot create an instance of interface.
Code is as below.

```
Dim cfg As New Configuration()
                cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment. _
                  ConnectionProvider, GetType(NHibernate.Connection. _
                  DriverConnectionProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName)

                cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, _
                  GetType(NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect). _
                  AssemblyQualifiedName)

                cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, _
                  GetType(NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver). _
                  AssemblyQualifiedName)
                cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionStringName, _
  "myconnectionstring")

                cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment. _
                  ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, GetType _
                  (NHibernate.Bytecode.IProxyFactoryFactory). _
                  AssemblyQualifiedName)

                Dim s2 As NHibernate.ISessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory
                db = s2.OpenSession()
```

error occurs at IproxyFactoryFactory.
I included all required references such as NHibernate.Linq, NHibernate.dialect etc
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment. _
              ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, GetType _
              (NHibernate.Bytecode.IProxyFactoryFactory). _
              AssemblyQualifiedName)
```

The ProxyFactoryFactoryClass is meant to be a class, but you are specifying an interface (NHibernate.Bytecode.IProxyFactoryFactory), change it to:

```
cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment. _
              ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, GetType _
              (NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory). _
              AssemblyQualifiedName)
```